# What is causing an infinite loop here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend, infinite-loop

I am relatively new to React and I don't fully understand where in my code is a re-rendering being called. I know the file is very large, sorry about that :(. I will remove the areas where I know that nothing is being re-rendered constantly.

Any ideas on where and why? Thanks.

CODE:

````
function MeetupItem(props) {
    useCallback(() => {
        setAllParticipants(participantContext.getParticipants(props));
        try {
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/users')
                .then(response => {
                    return response.json();
                }).then(data => {
                    const users = [];
                    for (const key in data) {
                        const user = {
                            id: key,
                            ...data[key]
                        };
                        users.push(user);
                    };
                    setAllPossibleParticipants(allParticipants.filter(users));
                    console.log(allParticipants);
                })
        } catch (err) { console.log(err) };
    }, [participantContext, props, allParticipants]);

}

export default MeetupItem;```
````

Comment: Try removing `allParticipants` from the dependancy array

Comment: nothing, I tried all three :(

Comment: Try removing everything in your component and return as little as possible (or even just null to begin with). Ensure it only renders once. Then gradually add things back in until you see it causing more rerenders than you expect.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are setting `allParticipants` in dependency array of `useCallback` and at the same time inside `useCallback` you are updating state of `allParticipants` it will cause infinite loop because this `useCallback` will execute whenever there is change in any of the items in dependency array.

modified code:

```
    useCallback(() => {
        setAllParticipants(participantContext.getParticipants(props));
        try {
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/users')
                .then(response => {
                    return response.json();
                }).then(data => {
                    const users = [];
                    for (const key in data) {
                        const user = {
                            id: key,
                            ...data[key]
                        };
                        users.push(user);
                    };
                    setAllPossibleParticipants(allParticipants.filter(users));
                    console.log(allParticipants);
                })
        } catch (err) { console.log(err) };
    }, [participantContext, props]);

}

export default MeetupItem;
```

See if above code solves your problem.

Comment: had to remove the first line. removing the dependencies was not enough :(

Answer (score 1):

when you use `useCallback` you should provide dependency array carefully. you have set `allParticipants` to the dependency array and then you have modified the value of this variable inside your code! as a result, after each change, your callback would run again and cause an infinite loop!

Answer (score 0):

If this line is updating `allParticipants`

```js
setAllPossibleParticipants(allParticipants.filter(users));
```

`useCallback` will be called again, as you `allParticipants` as it's dependency.